Lambda and std::function causing dangling reference (segmentation fault)
I have a Entity system (I tried to recreated a simpler ECS without much worry on memory placement...)
EntityManager:
class EntityManager
{
    static std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::list<Entity*>> entitiesMap;
public:
    static void RegisterEntity(std::type_index type, Entity* entity)
    {
        if (entitiesMap.find(type) == entitiesMap.end()) {
            entitiesMap.insert(std::pair<std::type_index, std::list<Entity*>>(
                type,
                std::list<Entity*>()
            ));
        }

        entitiesMap[type].push_back(entity);
    }

    template <class T>
    static void IterateEntities(std::function<void(T*)> method)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Entity, T>::value, "T must be derived from Entity");
        
        std::type_index type = std::type_index(typeid(T));

        auto targetIterator = entitiesMap.find(type);
        if (targetIterator != entitiesMap.end()) {
            for (Entity* entity : targetIterator->second) {
                method(dynamic_cast<T*>(entity));
            }
        }
    }
};

std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::list<Entity*>> EntityManager::entitiesMap;

Entity
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(std::type_index type)
    {
        EntityManager::RegisterEntity(type, this);
    }

    virtual ~Entity() = default;
};

main.cpp
class DerivedEntity : Entity
{
public:
    DerivedEntity(int s) : Entity(typeid(DerivedEntity)) 
    {
        id = s;
    }

    int id;

    void Notify()
    {
        printf("Notitied: %d", id); // <--- Segmentation fault
    }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedEntity *test = new DerivedEntity(0);
    EntityManager::IterateEntities<DerivedEntity>([](DerivedEntity* t) { t->Notify(); });
}

I think the problem was dangling reference since I tried to log the address inside Notify() it returns null
void Notify()
{
    printf("Log: %p", this); // Log
    printf("Notitied: %d", id);
}

while I log the entity before the std::function call, it returns the right object I looking for
printf("Log: %p", entity); // Log
method(dynamic_cast<T*>(entity));

How to fix it?

is entitiesMap supposed to be static as well? I can't see how else this could work...

Also I assume ObjA is meant to be DerivedEntity?

And finally you're doing dynamc_cast  on Entity which is not polymorphic. Add a virtual destructor and try again. You could have easily checked this by doing a straight dynamic cast in main and observing the result.

What's with all your dynamic_casts? They should not be necessary, just enure all your T (template types) are derived from an abstract baseclass (e.g. IEntity which has a pure virtual notify method). Or use concepts (or sfinae) to ensure your T implements a notify functions (static polymorphism). Your current design is not going to work

Side note ObjA *a0 = new ObjA(0); is useless use of new (and you end up with a memory leak).

oh. I tried to re-do some of my code to make it easier to read but forget to change some, sorry

It's really easy to do, which is why the best advice is always to write a minimal reproducible example that you can confirm locally, and then just paste into the question. Nobody wants to do this stuff manually when you have a compiler that can do it for you (and nobody wants to try reproducing a problem if they can't trust the code is exactly what produced the error)

Getting "source type is not polymorphic" when trying to use dynamic_cast and dynamic_cast and polymorphism

virtual ~Entity = default; isn't valid syntax, and it really should undo the registration, as otherwise you will have dangling pointers as soon as an entity is destroyed

Aside: RegisterEntity can be entitiesMap[type].push_back(entity);, operator[] on associative containers default constructs if the value isn't present

I can not see the point of using raw pointers. std::unique_ptr, or std:: variant work for most cases. You don't even need a new class. std::multimap, std::unordered_multimap, and std::flat_map implement your requirements with various levels of optimization. Maybe even set container family can be adapted for memory efficiency. The IterateEntities function is totally redundant. A combination of std::views::filter and std::views::transform is one liner; it doesn't even need a function definition.

Here's a bunch of issues fixed

wow, there're many things I didn't know about std and c++ as a whole, thank you!

I can't immediately find a great duplicate for this, so I'll answer properly.
Entity is not polymorphic, because it doesn't have any virtual methods.
You can see from the documentation that dynamic_cast only works for down-casting (what you're trying to do) when the source is polymorphic.
You can and should confirm that this is your issue by writing a simple dynamic_cast right in main. Examining your segmentation fault in a debugger (with a debug build) would also have given you some idea where this nullptr was coming from.
You can make Entity polymorphic by simply adding a virtual destructor. You should usually have one of these anyway if you might want to manage ownership using base-class pointers.
